# Http methods differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

What is difference between

```
HTTPPOST
HTTPDELETE
HTTPPUT
HTTPGET
```

Normally used post and get method for submit form and i know them very well but want to know with delete and put method when and why they can be used to improve programming skills

Comment: yes, it's called restful programming: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do

Comment: @F.Calderan: No, it's not, it's really not! ... http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post - "Specific method definitions simply don't matter to the REST architectural style" - (from the guy that invented REST).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the different methods do depends entirely on how the remote web server chooses to interpret them. There is no fixed meaning. A server does not care if it sees `GET` or `POST`; rather, the code that ends up being executed to service the request does (and can decide to do anything, since it's code).

The HTTP protocol gives an official guideline for what kind of action each verb is supposed to trigger, which is:

- GET: retrieve a resource
- PUT: replace a resource with another, or create it if it does not exist
- DELETE: remove a resource if it exists
- POST: might do anything; typically used to "add" to a resource

However this mapping is ultimately governed by application code and is typically not respected by web applications (e.g. you will see logical deletions being enacted with POST instead of DELETE).

The situation is better when talking about [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architectures over HTTP.

Comment: There _is_ a fixed meaning!  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html E.g. it would be important to check for duplicate POSTs, but there's no need to worry about duplicate GETs, PUTs or DELETEs, as long as the specification is being followed.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Idempotence and safety are attributes of the various verbs. That doesn't mean that the verbs have inherent meaning.

Comment: Huh? True, but they are just tangents that I chose to elaborate with, that doesn't mean the verbs do _not_ have inherent meaning, which I covered at the start of the comment by linking to "HTTP Method Definitions". That's _why_ there's a specification in the first place. GET does therefore _mean_ safe and idempotent according to the specification. It is fixed, it's in the specification. The problem is people implementing GET that is unsafe, therefore not following the specification. Just because it has no meaning to a server, does not mean there is no meaning.

Comment: Your answer suggests the definitions are in REST and not in HTTP, which is not accurate.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski: Is this version better?

Comment: Not sure: - The question is about HTTP, but F. Calderan turned it into a REST question it seems, which it is not. - HTTP has fixed meanings for methods. - Servers do behave differently to GET and POST (so do clients and proxies). - Yes you can decide to implement anything, but that's a bad idea (unless it's a POST). - HTTP is a standard not a guideline, if you expect a GET to do an update, it will soon fail because of browser caching. - Application code can be wrong, but that's not good. - The situation is worse when taking about REST architecture, because it's often misinformed or confused.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

- GET = fetch a resource.
- POST = update a resource.
- DELETE = delete a resource.
- PUT = create/replace a resource.

In HTML, only GET and POST are allowed.  A typical web-development HTTP server will do nothing unless you have code (or configuration) to specify what you want it to do with the different HTTP methods.

There's nothing stopping you from updating user data in response to a GET request, but it's not advisable. Browsers deal with GET and POST differently, with respect to caching the request (a cached GET will automatically be reissued, but a cached POST will prompt the user to allow it to be resent) and many HTML elements can issue GETs, making them unsafe for updates.  There are other HTTP methods too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol.

Many people who claim to be [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) will confuse HTTP POST and PUT with SQL UPDATE and INSERT.  There isn't a direct correlation, it always depends on context. That is, what POST means depends entirely on the resource that you're interacting with.  For example, creating a new entry on a blog could be a POST to the blog itself, or a PUT to a subordinate resource. However, a PUT, [by definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), must always contain the entire resource.

Typically, you would not allow a HTTP client to determine the URI of a new resource, so a POST to /blog would be safer than a PUT to /blog/*article-uri* although HTTP does cater for appropriate responses should the server be unable to honour the intended URI.  (HTTP is just a specification, you have to write the code to support it, or find a framework)

But as you can always achieve a PUT or DELETE use-case by POSTING to a parent resource responsible for its subordinates (i.e. POSTing a message to /mailbox instead of PUTting it at /mailbox/*message-id*), it isn't essential to expose PUT or DELETE methods publicly.

You can improve your programming skills by adopting REST principles to improve the visibility of the interactions within a system, it may be simpler to contextualise your interactions in terms of REST by having a uniform interface, for example.

REST is not HTTP though: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm.